# how to use name of name in array

Tags: tcl

I want to use name of name in array. I searched about dictionary but my tcl version is old so I couldn't use dictionary. also I couldn't upgrade tcl version. So Could you tell me how to use name of name like below script..?

```
set country korea
set food kimchi
set find($country)($food) spicy

set country japan
set food susi
set find($country)($food) fresh

set country international
set food hamburger
set find($country)($food) standard

set country international
set food chicken
set find($country)($food) standard

foreach country [array names find] {
 puts $index
}
# I expect 'korea japan international'.. but It wasn't working

foreach country [array names find] {
foreach food [array names find($country)] {

 puts $country,$food,$food($country)($food)
}
}
# I expect
# korea,kimch,spicy
# japan,susi,fresh
# international,hamburger,standard
# international,chicken,standard
# but It was not working..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use dictionaries, this means you're on Tcl 8.4 or before. These are not supported; **the minimum supported version of Tcl is 8.5** which is currently on long-term critical-bug-fix only grade support, and 8.6 is the recommended minimum for new work. *The formal advice is upgrade, even if this is impossible for you.*

---

So, you're stuck with dictionaries? You cannot nest those (except in a few ancient versions where it was possible via a bug) so you need to find a different approach. The simplest method might be to use one array that holds the name of another array. This is probably easiest if we use a few helper procedures:

```
# Initialise the array ahead of time
array set find {}

proc setFoodInfo {country food info} {
    upvar 1 find find
    if {![info exists find($country)]} {
        # Generate a unique array name
        set find($country) find_[array size find]
    }
    upvar 1 $find($country) ary
    set ary($food) $info
    return
}

proc listFoods {country} {
    upvar 1 find find
    upvar 1 $find($country) ary
    return [array names ary]
}

proc getFoodInfo {country food} {
    upvar 1 find find
    upvar 1 $find($country) ary
    return $ary($food)
}

setFoodInfo korea kimchi spicy
setFoodInfo japan sushi fresh
setFoodInfo international hamburger standard
setFoodInfo international chicken standard

foreach country [array names find] {
    foreach food [listFoods $country] {
        puts $country,$food,[getFoodInfo $country $food]
    }
}
```

When I test it in Tcl 8.4 — I fortunately still have a copy — I get this output:

```
international,chicken,standard
international,hamburger,standard
japan,sushi,fresh
korea,kimchi,spicy
```

Tcl doesn't preserve the order of arrays, so I consider this to be acceptably similar to what you are looking for.

---

The actual most common technique back in old Tcl versions was to use compound keys, often with `,` as the compounding character:

```
set find(korea,kimchi) spicy
...


foreach name [array names find] {
    puts $name,$find($name)
}
```

but this gets quite confusing when you want to ask questions like “what countries do I have information about foods for?”. It's not insurmountable for reasonable keys, as you can use a glob pattern with `array names` and parse the result (e.g., with `split` or `regexp`), but it's quite messy. (For this particular example, the *best* answer is to use an SQL database, but that involves an extra package and possibly more external setup.)